# Can't print out one element in Counting Sort

Tags: python, arrays, sorting

I tried to code Counting Sort algorithm with additional array, but somehow 1 element from randomly generated array doesn't print out.

```
import random
import time
start_time = time.clock()
N = random.randint(3,12)                                     
list1 = []*N
for i in range (1,N+1):                                       
    list1.insert(random.randint(1,100),random.randint(1,100)) 
print("Input array: ",list1)                                                  

B = [0]*(N+1)
for i in range(1,N):
    k = 1
    for j in range(1,N):
         if (list1[j]<list1[i]) or ((list1[j]==list1[i]) and (j<i)):
             k = k+1
    B[k]=list1[i]
for i in range(1,N):
    list1[i]=B[i]


print("Sorted array: ",B)
print("Amount of numbers in array: ",N)
print("Code is finished within",time.clock()-start_time, "seconds")
```

Comment: I don't like the look of those `range(1,N)`s. You know lists are zero-indexed, right?

Comment: After changing  all ranges and counter _k_ to 0, after sorting there was 1 extra zero, after it's deletion I got fully sorted array, but how can I correct that mistake, so sorted array wouldn't need any changes afterwards?

Comment: https://github.com/Nbody231/CountingSort/blob/master/CountingSortAlgorithm
That's fully working code for future generations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code from

```
B = [0]*(N+1)
    for i in range(1,N):
        k = 1
        for j in range(1,N):
```

to

```
B = [0]*(N)
for i in range(0,N):
    k = 0
    for j in range(0,N):
```

Because lists are zero-indexed.
This hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
import random
import time
start_time = time.clock()
N = random.randint(3,12)                                     
list1 = []*N
for i in range (N):                                       
    list1.insert(random.randint(1,100),random.randint(1,100)) 
print("Input array: ",list1)                                                  

B = [0]*(N+1)
for i in range(N):
    k = 1
    for j in range(N):
         if (list1[j]<list1[i]) or ((list1[j]==list1[i]) and (j<i)):
             k = k+1
    B[k]=list1[i]
for i in range(N):
    list1[i]=B[i]


print("Sorted array: ",B)
print("Amount of numbers in array: ",N)
print("Code is finished within",time.clock()-start_time, "seconds")


Input array:  [47, 28, 93, 92, 74, 13]
Sorted array:  [0, 13, 28, 47, 74, 92, 93]
```

In python, things are zero-indexed, so saying `range(1,N+1)` or `range(1,N)` skips over index 0

Comment: Ha-ha, sorry for spending your time, I realised that I was creating B = [0]*(N+1) and by this I was adding this last zero

Comment: No problem! I'm not sure whether the extra zero at the beginning of your sorted array is intentionally there; if not, just change add `B = B[1:]` after your last `for` loop